# iOS: on MKMapView, can't switch between MKMapTypeStandard and MKMapTypeMutedStandard types

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a MKMapView in my app, and I want the user to be able to switch the map type, so it can be either MutedStandard, Standard, Satellite or Hybrid. I've hooked up a UISegmentedControl on the Map view controller to change the map types. The problem is, as I try to switch between MutedStandard and Standard (or vice versa), the map view never updates! It works fine for every other type change ... and it works if I quit and reload the app, but the real-time map type change never works if it's just between MutedStandard and Standard.

The other strange thing is that it works fine on iOS12 ... just not on iOS13.

Here is the simple code that handles this:

```
- (IBAction) updateMapTypeSegmentControlValueChanged:(id)sender {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:self.segmentMapType.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:MapViewSettingsDisplayType];
    [self updateMapDisplayType];
}

- (void) updateMapDisplayType {
    NSUInteger mapType = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: MapViewSettingsDisplayType];
    switch (mapType) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSLog(@"MapView: updateMapDisplayType - setting to Muted");
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeMutedStandard;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            NSLog(@"MapView: updateMapDisplayType - setting to Standard");
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            NSLog(@"MapView: updateMapDisplayType - setting to Satellite");
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            NSLog(@"MapView: updateMapDisplayType - setting to Hybrid");
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeMutedStandard;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas of what I can try to make this work? I've tried using dispatch_after to make it change the type after 1 second, but that didn't work. Neither did calling `[mapView setNeedsDisplay]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don’t have to quit, but if you move the map at all, you’ll see the shift from muted to standard (or vice versa).

There are a variety of things you can do to trigger the redrawing. For example, if you’re on a physical device and using [`userTrackingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1616208-usertrackingmode?language=objc) of [`MKUserTrackingModeFollow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingmode/mkusertrackingmodefollow?language=occ) ([`.follow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingmode/follow) in Swift), you’ll tend to see it update reasonably quickly. Or I find that if I change it to satellite and immediately to muted/standard, you’ll see the change.  Or even easier, just set the `centerCoordinate` (even to its current value), and you’ll see the change:

```
- (void) updateMapDisplayType:(int)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeMutedStandard;
            break;

        case 1:
            self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;

        case 2:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;

        case 3:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;

        default:
            self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeMutedStandard;
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]

This is obviously just a kludge to get around what appears to be a bug. I’ll file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks! I found a different work-around, which was to call `[mapView setRegion:animated:]` and have the 'region' be a slightly different span than the current one. This also triggers the re-draw, though it does cause the zoom level to slightly change. I'll try setting just the centerCoordinate, which would avoid that zoom bounce.